# How can i compile program in static library?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, php-cpp

I used [php-cpp](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP)

and create program and worked fine in shared library and Makefile is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854229/how-can-i-compile-with-static-library)

but i want compile with static library

So i used this command:

`/opt/rh/devtool/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++ -c -std=c++11 md5.cpp  -o md5.o`
`/opt/rh/devtool/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++ -c -std=c++11 base64.cpp -o base64.o`
`/opt/rh/devtool/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++ -c -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main.o`

and create library with `ar rcs my_lib.a main.o base64.o md5.o`

and for compile used

`/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -o my_prog.o main.cpp base64.cpp md5.cpp my_lib.a`

but return error:

```
/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccYj8JlX.o: In function `parsekit(Php::Parameters&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `Php::SERVER'
main.cpp:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `Php::Value::~Value()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x82b): undefined reference to `Php::out'
main.cpp:(.text+0x851): undefined reference to `Php::Value::Value(bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8f1): undefined reference to `Php::out'
main.cpp:(.text+0x917): undefined reference to `Php::Value::Value(bool)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xab2): undefined reference to `Php::Value::Value(std::string const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb51): undefined reference to `Php::Value::~Value()'
/tmp/ccYj8JlX.o: In function `get_module':
main.cpp:(.text+0xe79): undefined reference to `Php::Extension::Extension(char const*, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe92): undefined reference to `Php::Extension::~Extension()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xecc): undefined reference to `Php::Namespace::add(char const*, Php::Value (* const&)(Php::Parameters&), std::initializer_list<Php::Argument> const&)'
/tmp/ccYj8JlX.o: In function `Php::Value::operator std::string() const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK3Php5ValuecvSsEv[_ZNK3Php5ValuecvSsEv]+0x1f): undefined reference to `Php::Value::stringValue() const'
/tmp/ccYj8JlX.o: In function `Php::Super::operator[](char const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc[_ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc]+0x24): undefined reference to `Php::Super::value()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc[_ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc]+0x3d): undefined reference to `Php::Value::get(char const*, int) const'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc[_ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc]+0x49): undefined reference to `Php::Value::~Value()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc[_ZN3Php5SuperixEPKc]+0x5a): undefined reference to `Php::Value::~Value()'
/tmp/ccYj8JlX.o: In function `Php::Extension::operator void*()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Php9ExtensioncvPvEv[_ZN3Php9ExtensioncvPvEv]+0x14): undefined reference to `Php::Extension::module()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i compile with Static Library?

Answer (score 0):

you need to link in phpcpp aswell

Comment: How can i? please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Errors you're getting indicate that linker can't find php-cpp library (your compiled code references its symbols). You have to specify the library path with `-l` flag and then link it like this: [Mixing static libraries and shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438891/mixing-static-libraries-and-shared-libraries)

Comment: i used `/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -shared -fpic -lphpcpp -o my_prog.o main.cpp base64.cpp md5.cpp my_lib.a` and compiled, but is not static, and not work on other OS

Comment: `-fpic` is for shared library creation, you have to use `-static` (requires php-cpp also to be compiled as static)

Comment: do you have static version of phpcpp installed?

Comment: i used `/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -static -lphpcpp -o my_prog.o main.cpp base64.cpp md5.cpp my_lib.a` but return error again on the my post

Comment: i installed with this document http://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/install i dont known is static or shared