# Using static library in a shared library created with CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm using a compiled library that I made, `libexp.a`. (Was compiled with PIC so its good for this use case).

I want to use it statically in my shared library and I can do that via [Mixing static libraries and shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438891/mixing-static-libraries-and-shared-libraries).

So now I'm trying to get that working with `CMake`, my `libexp.a` is in the root directory and I do:

```
find_library(EXP NAMES exp PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Then using it in `target_link_libraries` via `${EXP}`, but during link time I still get a linking error of couldn't find `-lexp`. What is the right way to get this done? Using over 3.6

Comment: Why are you writing `$\{PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` instead of `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` as is normally done?

Comment: sorry, that was leftover, assume syntax is correct